# Hiding certain values in layer on ArcPad

Tags: arcpad, trimble, visibility

My organization uses ArcPad 10 on a Trimble nomad. We have many data points in an environmental survey layer, but I would like to only display points from the last two years on ArcPad to help add clarity to the field map.

Is there a way to hide the older data on ArcPad, while not deleting it from the associated ArcMap document?

I have tried creating a new layer from selected points of the desired years on ArcMap, then uploading that to the Nomad, but all of the old points are still visible.

Comment: I am not sure about doing it on ArcPad, but you should look for a way to implement a definition query via ArcPad.

Comment: *May* not be possible due to a bug - see https://geonet.esri.com/thread/32011 which also refers to it as a filter in ArcPad. There's talk there of setting a definition query in a map document and then checking out just the queried features, but that thread goes into detail of it not working in all cases.

Comment: Have you tried using symbology to not colour the points in the layer that you want to hide? a better solution would be to strip out the data you want to hide especially if there are a lot of points and only have the ones you want to show.